# Reduce Chromium re-compilation time

Tags: build, chromium, rebuild

Every time I execute `git rebase-update & gclient sync -D`, it will take me 4-5 hours to recompile. Is there any method to reduce the time needed?

Comment: When you run those commands, it will download new version of Chromium and third-party libraries. So it will start compiling again, that's why it will take longer to Compile. You should run those commands to fetch a new version of Chromium only

Comment: @Asesh Oh, I execute this command to periodic keep my chromium updated or when there are some conflicts with my local modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use compiler cache: https://ccache.dev/
- I'm not familiar with Chromium, so if there's any option to exclude building code for architectures other than your computer's, use that.
- Don't build tests etc if you don't run them.
- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/mac_build_instructions.md#Faster-builds
- Ask on Chromium forum/ discussion groups https://www.chromium.org/developers/discussion-groups